# Using .NET class from native C++ using C++/CLI as a 'middleware'

Tags: c#, c++, interop, c++-cli

I have to use a class/assembly made in C# .NET from native C++ application.
I suppose I need to make a wrapper class in C++/CLI, that would expose native methods in header files, but use .NET class as needed. 
Thing that's unclear to me is how to convert data types from .NET to standard C++ types.

Does anybody have some sample code to learn from?

Only text I have found on this is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300632.aspx

But text is very old (using Managed C++, not C++/CLI), and lot of things remains unclear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you need to build a wrapper with C++/CLI around your managed assembly.

For mixing native and managed types you may want to check [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2005/07/12/Mixing-Native-and-Managed-Types-in-C_2B002B00_.aspx) article for sample 
codes.

Primitive types has int, float, byte are converted for you. But other types has String must be done yourself. For example, if you have a native pointer on a char*, then your C++/CLI class will have to convert it to a String in order to be passed to your Managed C# assembly.